# Toggle extensions via bat or vbs

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, file-rename, batch-rename

I need to quickly toggle the extension of all files contained in a specific folder.

Suppose that `C:\My Folder\` contains 200 files (all `.txt`).

BY EXECUTING THE SCRIPT I change them all to `.xml`

and then

BY EXECUTING **THE SAME** SCRIPT AGAIN I change them all back to `.txt`.

In other words executing **this one** script will indefinitely turn these 200 files (if they are `.txt`) to `.xml` and (if they are `.xml`) to `.txt` and loop...

For a batch I had in mind something like this (which does **not** work):

```
@echo off

IF EXIST "C:\My Folder\*.txt" GOTO RENAMETXT
IF NOT EXIST "C:\My Folder\*.txt" GOTO RENAMEXML

:RENAMETXT
ren "C:\My Folder\*.txt" "*.xml"

:RENAMEXML
ren "C:\My Folder\*.xml" "*.txt"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed batch script does not work because the `:RENAMETXT` portion falls through to `:RENAMEXML`. It could be fixed by simply inserting `EXIT /B` before `:RENAMEXML`.

But there is no need for GOTO or EXIT /B - You can simply use IF ... ELSE ...

```
@echo off
if exist "C:\My Folder\*.txt" (
  ren "C:\My Folder\*.txt" *.xml
) else (
  ren "C:\My Folder\*.xml" *.txt
)
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting my error (the missing EXIT /B part) and thanks also for the (much simpler) IF...ELSE... solution, which, BTW I did try myself earlier but since I forgot to add the parenthesis it (obviously) did not work ;) ... Now I know why! Cheers!

Comment: @dbenham - At least for Win XP and 7, the second parameter to ren has to be a 'filename': cp. "ren /? => REN [drive:][path]filename1 filename2. ... Note that you cannot specify a new drive or path for your destination file."

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner - Of course you are correct, thanks. Silly mistake on my part. All fixed.

Comment: @EtaBeta - Please read Ekkehard's comment and look at the revised answer. It was bugged before.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that the destination file path was redundant, but (as I **obviously** did not intend to change the extension of files under a different path) it did work just fine for the job I had to do :) I am actually running the .bat from within the same dir and therefore I trimmed it down to this: @echo off
if exist "*.txt" (ren "*.txt" "*.xml") else (ren "*.xml" "*.txt")